# Blender crashes whole PC

Tags: windows

Blender crashes my whole PC, usually when i switch out of it and come back into it.

Blender usually crashes when I switch out of it and come back into, and when it does crash, it begins with the whole system becoming barely responsive and blender completely unresponsive, and even if i do manage to close blender, my PC remains unresponsive and crashed afterwards.

Sometimes my PC just freezes and other times it blue screens, in which case I get the

**error**

- dcp_watchdog_violation or driver_power_state_failure.

I already tried re-installing blender (2.8) and re-installing windows
   10 (while keeping files and apps). My PC, as far as I know, only
   crashes when using blender.

Comment: Try to update your graphics driver. A crashing driver could cause a blue screen.

Comment: You should report a bug. Go to the Help menu and choose "Report a bug" follow the instructions so developers can track down what is causing this issue.

Comment: No, do not report a bug unless you have updated your drivers and that didn't fix the problem. I had this problem, and it was fixed by updating the GPU driver. If you're using the current drivers and are experiencing crashes, then there might be a bug, but you can't tell if there is a bug if you are using an outdated driver.

Answer (score 1):

### your driver is not compatible.

You need the dump file to determine the error, but maybe if you update your driver you can solve the problem. It is worth saying that if you use Windows, this brings a generic driver, so it is recommended to use the driver provided by the manufacturer of the peripheral you are using, otherwise you would have to see your dump file as I have already mentioned.

Do a Google search with this line and you will get a sea of information about your problem:

- "dcp_watchdog_violation o driver_power_state_failure."

Comment: I have tried searching up the error codes and didnt find anything that helped me, but i'll try getting drivers for my peripherals. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Never Mind after trying everything I forgot about rolling back by gpu drivers, so its fixed now so thanks for the advice.